# Where is the package list?

Tags: release-management

I would like to know what version of glibc will be used in later releases.  Is that information available?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glibc&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all :)

Comment: By the way: any information from that link is bound the change as 16.04 gets on the road since it originally is copied from 15.10 and then new software is added (so new versions will be included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for package lists have a look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

there is also a list of [all sections](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/) or [all packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/allpackages) for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial).

at the moment for *glibc* [this can be offered](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glibc&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all)...
--> this means for now it can't be answered completely because a feature freeze is usually approximately 2 months before the release, so there might change something!

Comment: Could be a good answer. :\

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's "feature freeze" is usually a couple of months before release. Until that happens, the versions of packages in the development version of the next release will continue to change,staying roughly in sync with Debian's Testing release (or is it Unstable? Note to self:check and edit this answer).

That said, it is rare in the extreme for package versions to go *down*, especially at this point in the development cycle.

Right now, therefore, there is no way to know what version of a given package will be in the final release - but you can establish a lower bound.